# Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, app-secret

i have created an app in my facebook account and done post to my friend using my access token (php).

But another user cannot post to their friend using my app id and secret and getting the error

> Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument

i have disabled

> Required app secret proof in my app settings

any solution please?

```
public function facebookUsershare() { 
require '../facebook/src/facebook.php'; $facebook = new Facebook(array( 'appId' => 'app     id', 'secret' => 'secret_key', )); 

$privacy = array( 'description' => 'Vladimir Sergeevich', 'value' => 'CUSTOM', 'friends'   =>'friend id' 'allow' => 'loged in user' );
try {
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array( "access_token" => 'access_token',   'picture' => "path to image", 'link' => "gmail.com";, 'name' => "Go wi6 7", 'caption' =>   "capn", 'privacy' => json_encode($privacy) ));

echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook Personal Profile'; //return $facebookfrndids; }   catch(Exception $e) { 
echo $e->getMessage(); 
return false; }
```

Comment: You should edit your question instead of posting codes in Comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally i got the answer....
disable Required app secret proof in the advanced settings of app, and comment the following code in base_facebook.php sdk

```
if (isset($params['access_token'])) {
  $params['appsecret_proof'] = $this->getAppSecretProof($params['access_token']);
}
```

Comment: You should not do this. Update your php sdk files.

Comment: As of SDK v4.0.11, you can use `FacebookSession::enableAppSecretProof(false);` to control this

Comment: You either use FacebookSession::enableAppSecretProof(false); or you turn on require app secret proof in your facebook app console. You don't need to do anything when using official facebook SDK, as long as you set your facebook app secret correct in your web server.

Comment: disable Required app secret proof in the advanced settings of app if you don't have it or if it blank - works for me

Answer (score 2):

As for [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests/):

> Graph API calls can be made from clients or from your server on behalf
>   of clients. Calls from a server can be better secured by adding a
>   parameter called appsecret_proof.

So you need to specify additional param `appsecret_proof` togather with `access_token`. The `appsecret_proof` is digital signature of `access_token` that signed with your app secret. The signature need to confirm `access_token`. To get `appsecret_proof` you need to calculate signature like this:

```
secret = 'app secret'
token = 'access token'
digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256')
proof = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, secret, token)

# result params:
"access_token=#{token}&appsecret_proof=#{proof}"
```

The example is on Ruby language but this is not language problem. Please refer your language manual to refer for **hmac** signature api.

Comment: whereshould i passed this `appsecret_proof`. i m using php.

Comment: togater with access_token, in request body